# How To Get unique id number

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='post-1286781' class='post'></div>
<div id='post-1202828' class='post'></div>
<div id='post-5654112' class='post'></div>
<div id='post-6353422' class='post'></div>
<div id='post-7256287' class='post'></div>
<div id='post-6725282' class='post'></div>
<div id='post-5242611' class='post'></div>
<div id='post-7162527' class='post'></div>
```

This is the HTML

Can anyone give me a solution that how can I get the unique id number of the posts using jQuery.

I must get the result like

post-*id Number*

it must be obtained via pure jQuery

Because when I use class selector then it encounters the problem

Comment: I assume that you mean pure JavaScript, as jQuery is a framework which contains no string manipulation methods.

Comment: "pure jQuery" is good – never heard of that…

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` to get the numeric value. Try this:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var num = this.id.split('-')[1];
    console.log(num);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your HTML to use `data-*` attributes

```
<div data-post-id='1286781' class='post'></div>
```

Then

```
$('div.post').each(function(){
 var postId=$(this).data("post-id");
});
```

Option 2:

```
<div id='post-1286781' class='post'></div>

 $('div.post').each(function(){
 var postId=  this.split('-')[1];
 );
```

Comment: Option 1 is not a solution, but a workaround to not address the prblem. I removed the -1 after Option 2 was added…

Answer (score 0):

A plain JS port of the answer from Rory McCrossan using split: (IE8+)

Lazy looping (will output the post ID in reversed order compared to the position in the markup):

```
var posts = document.querySelector( '.post' );
for( var i = posts.length; i--; ) {
    var num = posts[i].id.split( '-' )[1];
    console.log( num );
}
```

Loop with correct order:

```
var posts = document.querySelector( '.post' );
for( var i = 0, len = posts.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var num = posts[i].id.split( '-' )[1];
    console.log( num );
}
```